# I'm getting "} Expected" Error even though I have matching braces

Tags: c#

when I was writing my code I got an error that I was missing a '}' on line 6. When I do put a } there, it tells me to put a { there instead. Since I'm new to Unity development, I might've just been stupid and not seen the problem, but here is the full error message if you need it:  Assets\Scripts\Difficulty.cs(16,6): error CS1513: } expected. Here is the code too:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Difficulty : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int difficulty;
    [SerializeField]
    float time;

    float timer = 0;  

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        public bool updated = false;
        float timer = time;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (time < 0)
        {
            updated = true;
            difficulty++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot declare local variables to be public

```
void Start()
{
    public bool updated = false;
    float timer = time;
}
```

move the `public bool...` line into the class scope, like `int difficulty` is

Not really sure what the line underneath is hoping to do, but avoid making local variables the same name as class scoped ones. You already have a `float timer` declared at class level, don't declare another at local method level

Comment: +1, tested locally, and @ anyone from Microsoft's C# team, this should be on your list of things to fix in the compiler, the error message should make sense, call out the term "public" being used inside a method

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable.. if you're in a method scope and you try to declare a class scope variable you'd have to put a } first to leave the method and be back in the class.. it's thus a choice of "error, close the method before you try to declare this class var", or "error, cannot declare a class var in a method".. potayto, potahto.. One cannot just fix a program by doing as the compiler says in an error; you'll probably end up with a syntactically correct, semantically incorrect mishmash..

Comment: (If you think about it, it's way more likely a person typoed by leaving out a single } to close the method, than it is the accidentally typoed the entire word "public" when they (should) know full well that local vars cannot be public.. So of those two choices, "missing }" is probably more reasonable to alert to.. eventually, when all the c# rules are learned, this error won't happen, but the missing } typo still might)

Comment: Yes, among professional programmers, but new programmers using Unity make this mistake ***ALL*** (visualize eye roll here) the time and gum up SO with silly questions about this issue. A different message would be helpful. Mind you, I'm not normally one to argue for targeting the lowest common denominator (betterment usually lags when you do), but this is a measured exception.

Comment: I had a brief Twitter conversation with @EricLippert (given his MS C# history) and then reported the issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58543, not sure if the error message can actually be fixed but at least folks are aware of it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there was another question just today (since deleted) where somone tried to declare a `struct` within `Main` and got the same error message -- similarly unhelpful -- and yet, the local functions were just fine. Local functions (likely unintentional) made the `struct` look like it was in the right context.